# MethodNotDefined: ('impl', , 'Round3') Apply node that caused the error

Tags: python-3.x, g++, gpu, theano

I m getting the following error when running the below code. It stops at training.

> WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not available, if using conda: `conda install m2w64-toolchain` D:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\theano\configdefaults.py:560:
>
> UserWarning: DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler.This is deprecated and with Theano 0.11 a c++ compiler will be mandatory warnings.warn("DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler."
>
> WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
>
> WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions.
>
> ```
>   batch_size = 100
>   alpha = 0.1
>   epsilon = 0.0001
>   num_units = 8
>   n_hidden_layers = 3
>   num_epochs = 1000
>   dropout_in = 0.2
>   dropout_hidden = 0.5
>   activation = binary_net.binary_tanh_unit
>   binary = True
>   stochastic = False
>   H = 1.0
>   W_LR_scale = Glorot
>   LR_start = 0.003
>   LR_fin = 3e-07
>   LR_decay = 0.9908319448927676
>   save_path = mnist_parameters.npz
>   shuffle_parts = 1
>   Loading MNIST dataset...
>   Building the MLP...
>   W_LR_scale = 22.97825
>   H = 1.0
>   W_LR_scale = 3.2659864
>   H = 1.0
>   W_LR_scale = 3.2659864
>   H = 1.0
>   W_LR_scale = 3.4641016
>   H = 1.0
>   Training...
> ```
>
> ​
>   MethodNotDefined: ('impl', , 'Round3')
>   Apply node that caused the error: Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (i1 + (i0 * round3(clip(i2, i3, i4)))) * i5)}}[(0, 2)](TensorConstant{(1, 1) of 2.0}, TensorConstant{(1, 1) of -1.0}, Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (i1 + (i2 * i3 * i4) + i5))}}.0, TensorConstant{(1, 1) of 0}, TensorConstant{(1, 1) of 1}, Elemwise{Composite{Cast{float32}(LT(i0, i1))}}[(0, 0)].0)
>   Toposort index: 82
>   Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, (True, True)), TensorType(float32, (True, True)), TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(int8, (True, True)), TensorType(int8, (True, True)), TensorType(float32, matrix)]
>   Inputs shapes: [(1, 1), (1, 1), (100, 8), (1, 1), (1, 1), (100, 8)]
>   Inputs strides: [(4, 4), (4, 4), (32, 4), (1, 1), (1, 1), (32, 4)]
>   Inputs values: [array([[2.]], dtype=float32), array([[-1.]], dtype=float32), 'not shown', array([[0]], dtype=int8), array([[1]], dtype=int8), 'not shown']
>   Outputs clients: [[InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}(Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (i1 + (i0 * round3(clip(i2, i3, i4)))) * i5)}}[(0, 2)].0), Dot22(Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (i1 + (i0 * round3(clip(i2, i3, i4)))) * i5)}}[(0, 2)].0, Elemwise{Composite{Switch(RoundHalfToEven(clip((i0 * (i1 + i2)), i3, i4)), i1, i5)}}.0)]]
>
> HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
>   HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.

Here below is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys 
import os
import time

import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)  # for reproducibility

import theano.tensor as T

import lasagne
from lasagne.layers import get_all_layers
import pickle
import gzip

import binary_net

from pylearn2.datasets.mnist import MNIST
from pylearn2.utils import serial

from collections import OrderedDict

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # BN parameters
    batch_size = 100
    print("batch_size = "+str(batch_size))
    # alpha is the exponential moving average factor
    # alpha = .15
    alpha = .1
    print("alpha = "+str(alpha))
    epsilon = 1e-4
    print("epsilon = "+str(epsilon))

    # MLP parameters
    num_units = 8
    print("num_units = "+str(num_units))
    n_hidden_layers = 3
    print("n_hidden_layers = "+str(n_hidden_layers))

    # Training parameters
    num_epochs = 1000
    print("num_epochs = "+str(num_epochs))

    # Dropout parameters
    dropout_in = .2 # 0. means no dropout
    print("dropout_in = "+str(dropout_in))
    dropout_hidden = .5
    print("dropout_hidden = "+str(dropout_hidden))

    # BinaryOut
    activation = binary_net.binary_tanh_unit
    print("activation = binary_net.binary_tanh_unit")
    # activation = binary_net.binary_sigmoid_unit
    # print("activation = binary_net.binary_sigmoid_unit")

    # BinaryConnect
    binary = True
    print("binary = "+str(binary))
    stochastic = False
    print("stochastic = "+str(stochastic))
    # (-H,+H) are the two binary values
    # H = "Glorot"
    H = 1.
    print("H = "+str(H))
    # W_LR_scale = 1.    
    W_LR_scale = "Glorot" # "Glorot" means we are using the coefficients from Glorot's paper
    print("W_LR_scale = "+str(W_LR_scale))

    # Decaying LR 
    LR_start = .003
    print("LR_start = "+str(LR_start))
    LR_fin = 0.0000003
    print("LR_fin = "+str(LR_fin))
    LR_decay = (LR_fin/LR_start)**(1./num_epochs)
    print("LR_decay = "+str(LR_decay))
    # BTW, LR decay might good for the BN moving average...

    save_path = "mnist_parameters.npz"
    print("save_path = "+str(save_path))

    shuffle_parts = 1
    print("shuffle_parts = "+str(shuffle_parts))

    print('Loading MNIST dataset...')

    train_set = MNIST(which_set= 'train', start=0, stop = 50000, center = False)
    valid_set = MNIST(which_set= 'train', start=50000, stop = 60000, center = False)
    test_set = MNIST(which_set= 'test', center = False)

    # bc01 format    
    # Inputs in the range [-1,+1]
    # print("Inputs in the range [-1,+1]")
    train_set.X = 2* train_set.X.reshape(-1, 1, 28, 28) - 1.
    valid_set.X = 2* valid_set.X.reshape(-1, 1, 28, 28) - 1.
    test_set.X = 2* test_set.X.reshape(-1, 1, 28, 28) - 1.

    # flatten targets
    train_set.y = np.hstack(train_set.y)
    valid_set.y = np.hstack(valid_set.y)
    test_set.y = np.hstack(test_set.y)

    # Onehot the targets
    train_set.y = np.float32(np.eye(10)[train_set.y])    
    valid_set.y = np.float32(np.eye(10)[valid_set.y])
    test_set.y = np.float32(np.eye(10)[test_set.y])

    # for hinge loss
    train_set.y = 2* train_set.y - 1.
    valid_set.y = 2* valid_set.y - 1.
    test_set.y = 2* test_set.y - 1.

    print('Building the MLP...') 

    # Prepare Theano variables for inputs and targets
    input = T.tensor4('inputs')
    target = T.matrix('targets')
    LR = T.scalar('LR', dtype=theano.config.floatX)

    mlp = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(
            shape=(None, 1, 28, 28),
            input_var=input)

    mlp = lasagne.layers.DropoutLayer(
            mlp, 
            p=dropout_in)

    for k in range(n_hidden_layers):

        mlp = binary_net.DenseLayer(
                mlp, 
                binary=binary,
                stochastic=stochastic,
                H=H,
                W_LR_scale=W_LR_scale,
                nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.identity,
                num_units=num_units)                  

        mlp = lasagne.layers.BatchNormLayer(
                mlp,
                epsilon=epsilon, 
                alpha=alpha)

        mlp = lasagne.layers.NonlinearityLayer(
                mlp,
                nonlinearity=activation)

        mlp = lasagne.layers.DropoutLayer(
                mlp, 
                p=dropout_hidden)

    mlp = binary_net.DenseLayer(
                mlp, 
                binary=binary,
                stochastic=stochastic,
                H=H,
                W_LR_scale=W_LR_scale,
                nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.identity,
                num_units=10)    

    mlp = lasagne.layers.BatchNormLayer(
            mlp,
            epsilon=epsilon, 
            alpha=alpha)

    train_output = lasagne.layers.get_output(mlp, deterministic=False)

    # squared hinge loss
    loss = T.mean(T.sqr(T.maximum(0.,1.-target*train_output)))

    if binary:

        # W updates
        W = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(mlp, binary=True)
        W_grads = binary_net.compute_grads(loss,mlp)
        updates = lasagne.updates.adam(loss_or_grads=W_grads, params=W, learning_rate=LR)
        updates = binary_net.clipping_scaling(updates,mlp)

        # other parameters updates
        params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(mlp, trainable=True, binary=False)
        updates = OrderedDict(list(updates.items()) + list(lasagne.updates.adam(loss_or_grads=loss, params=params,learning_rate=LR).items()))

    else:
        params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(mlp, trainable=True)
        updates = lasagne.updates.adam(loss_or_grads=loss, params=params, learning_rate=LR)

    test_output = lasagne.layers.get_output(mlp, deterministic=True)
    test_loss = T.mean(T.sqr(T.maximum(0.,1.-target*test_output)))
    test_err = T.mean(T.neq(T.argmax(test_output, axis=1), T.argmax(target, axis=1)),dtype=theano.config.floatX)

    # Compile a function performing a training step on a mini-batch (by giving the updates dictionary) 
    # and returning the corresponding training loss:
    train_fn = theano.function([input, target, LR], loss, updates=updates)

    # Compile a second function computing the validation loss and accuracy:
    val_fn = theano.function([input, target], [test_loss, test_err])

    print('Training...')

    binary_net.train(
            train_fn,val_fn,
            mlp,
            batch_size,
            LR_start,LR_decay,
            num_epochs,
            train_set.X,train_set.y,
            valid_set.X,valid_set.y,
            test_set.X,test_set.y,
            save_path,
            shuffle_parts)
```

Can anyone please help to solve this error.

Comment: Check the edits I made in your question and see if all coding alignments are correct... What a mess was this!

Comment: -ZF007  thank you,i'm actually posting for the fisrt time and i didn't know how to do it right

Comment: No worries.. you'll get the hang if it. If you tried things to fix it but didn't work you can update your question by editing it any time you like. Be sure to implement the info at the bottom of the question and start with a statement "update 1:", etc... Enjoy SO.